# Does user input need to be hashed before being used in password_verify?

Tags: php, sql, security, hash, passwords

I have an input field where the users enter their username and password. Do I need to hash the password that they input or is it ok to leave it and just use it in password_verify against the hashed database password. I am using password_hash to hash them with PASSWORD_BCRYPT and don't know how to compare them if I have to hash the input as well as the stored password.

Comment: You don't need to hash the password from the input field.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you use `password_hash` or similar functions to hash your passwords you should not hash the password before testing it with `password_verify`. At least as long as you don't "double hash it" which is quite useless.

The `password_hash` method will return a value which contains which hash it uses, the salt and the cost. So when it's passed to the `verify_password` method the method will know what to do with the clear text password passed as first argument.

You can read about all this at the PHP docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: I was slightly worried about it being a security issue. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: The password will always have to be passed in clear text to the server (why is why you wish to use TLS for transfer), you never store the password in clear text, you store the hash from `password_hash` and only verify with the `password_verify`, as long as you don't store the password in other form than the hashed value, it should be secure enough. :)

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_logons WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Password FROM user_logons");
  $result_data = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  $hash = strval($result_data[0]);
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query , 'ss' , $username , $_POST["password"]);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
  if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $hash)) {
   echo "Correct Password";
  }
  else {
   echo "Incorrect Password";
  }
 }`

Comment: Is that ok (as i haven't stored the plaintext password)

Comment: I don't think you should query for the username and password, but rather just fetch the password that the username matches then verify it with the user input, something like the following (not tested):
```$username = null;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT Password FROM user_logons WHERE Username = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->bind_result($password);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
    // success
}```

Comment: I cannot get this to work `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $username = $_POST["username"]; 
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT Password FROM user_logons WHERE Username = ? LIMIT 1"); 
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
  $stmt->bind_result($password); 
  $stmt->fetch(); 
  $stmt->close(); 
  if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) { 
   echo "Correct Password";
  }
  else {
   echo "Incorrect Password";
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary, but [**you can do that**](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#bcrypt) if you're expecting users to supply passwords longer than 71 characters.

If you decide to pre-hash, don't just pass a raw binary string to `password_hash()`/`password_verify()`. You'll end up creating another weakness.

The example code for the accompanying article demonstrates [Bcrypt-SHA384](https://gist.github.com/paragonie-scott/66469d391deef2e3b875) in this exact setup.